# postgresDB save operation fails with org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

Tags: postgresql, psql

In the table there is a field "isExpensive"  with character datatype.

This field can have values either "Y" or "N" or even may not be available in the request(in certain conditions).

In those conditions where "isExpensive" has a value either 'Y' or 'N', the request does not fail.

But when "isExpensive" is not present in the request it fails to get saved in db and fails with org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your datatype. If it is char , the primitive one , you might get this error because of default value of char. But changing to "Character" datatype might solve your issue